# Code scaffolding tool for VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fluent-nhibernate, scaffolding

Is there any good free scaffolding tool for Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3 project? I am looking for ability of generation code for entities, DAO, services and (it will be great) fluent NHibernate mappings and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an obvious answer, but have you seen the MVC Scaffolding stuff that Steve Sanderson has put together -

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/category/scaffolding/